# php array access on boolean

Tags: php

I recently stumbled across the following:

```
<? $d=false; var_dump($d[123]); ?>
```

which yielded `NULL`, but (unexpected to me) **without** any notice, as for example

```
<? $d=array(); var_dump($d[123]); ?>
```

does produce the well known

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset:  123 in - on line 1
```

What is going on here? Is there any documentation of this behavior?

Comment: That's pretty sad behaviour, if you ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Accessing variables of other types (not including arrays or 
>       objects implementing the appropriate interfaces) using [] or {} 
>       silently returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that is what you would call undefined behaviour.

It makes sense, as a boolean can not have an offset.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$d = TRUE; 
var_dump($d[0]);
```

This also produces `NULL` (if `FALSE` was coerced to an empty string, it would make sense that `TRUE` would be `1`).

Plus what [meze said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426695/php-array-access-on-boolean/5426755#5426755) :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick look at [the source code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_execute.c#zend_fetch_dimension_address_read) shows that this is expected behavior. But don't ask me why they did it this way...